# Partitionning disk for installation, what size should I give to filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, partition

I am planning to install debian on dual boot, I have 250GB free for that, but I d prefer answer for any size.

I want to separate filesystem on different partition (`/`, `/boot`, `/root`, `/home`, `/var`), but I m wondering about what size should I allow to each one.

On relative, how much space should I allow to each one? What is the vital minimum for each?

Comment: This is up to your own need and appreciation, you should get some info about what all those partion contains identify which should be the biggest and then use the partitionning that feets your need.

Comment: @Kiwy: I understand that, that s why I asked for a vital minimum too. It s basically to have an idea of how to order size by "folder".

Comment: I recommend using an own LV or mountpoint for /var/log, /tmp, /var/tmp, too.

Comment: @Nils: What size should I allow for thoses if so?

Comment: Our current standard is 4 GB each for /tmp and /var/tmp and 8 GB for /var/log on physical servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is certainly subjective and up to your specific needs. Nevertheless, as a general guideline, these are the minimum and recommended values (rounded) that Ubuntu recommends on a [relevant page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace):

- /: min: 8GB, recommended: 15GB (I would say 20GB is nice)
- /boot: min: 250MB, recommended: 1GB
- /root: no recommendation (I wouldn't expect much to be stored in it anyway in a typical desktop use).
- /var: min: 1GB, recommended: 2GB (be careful though if you host web sites, use /var/backups or mail server etc).
- /home: for desktop use I would recon all remaining space, it really depends on your files.

Comment: So 6% for `/`, 0.5% for `/boot`, 1% for `/var`, some % for `/root` and everything else in `/home`.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Converting to percentage does not make sense at all. The requirements for `/` do not change depending on the total size of the disk. You can easily install Linux on a 20Gb drive (total size), but you will run into trouble if you allocate 6% of that for `/`.

Comment: You are right in general. @DrakaSAN states the capacity in his question though.

Comment: You use the higher between the recommended and minimal size, I didn t thought about precising it thought.

Comment: @DrakaSAN once again the porucentage you express are related to the fact you have a 250gb on a 100Gb disk you can try thos and you will never be able to run your whole system correctly

Comment: Forgot to mention that you have to be extra careful to clear up old kernel images that are left from updates because otherwise in time relevant partitions will become full which is definitely not good.